# Combine 3 async to one observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I have 3 observables that I use for filter html part

Here is typescript part

```
   fiscalYear$ = this.store$.select(this.tableStoreService.getFiscalYear);
      isLoading$ = this.store$.select(this.tableStoreService.tableSelectors.getLoading);
isReportLoading$ = this.store$.select(isReportLoading);
```

All of this values has `Observable<boolean>` in return type.

Then I use it like this to filter html in `[disabled]`

```
<button class="btn btn-primary font-weight-700 font-size-200" [disabled]="(isReportLoading$ | async) || (fiscalYear$ | async) < 2022 || (isLoading$ | async) " (click)="clickExport()">
          {{ 'homepage.export' | translate }}
          <mat-icon class="btn-icon export-icon" svgIcon="export"></mat-icon>
        </button>
```

I try to do it like this

```
get isExportAvialable$() {
    return combineLatest(this.fiscalYear$, this.isLoading$, this.isReportLoading$, (fiscalYear, isLoading, isReportLoading) => isReportLoading || fiscalYear < 2022 || isLoading);
  }
```

But `fiscalYear < 2022` is showing error

How I can combine it to use only one with async?

Comment: fiscalYear is still an observable so you can't read that value that way. combineLatest is a correct way to go though, all you need it to pipe those combined obs into a map that figures out the logic so that the combined obs only returns a boolean based on your conditions. Take note though - you're using a getter function which is not a good idea. just use isExportAvailable$ as a component variable.

Comment: I would recommend you use a selector instead of combineLatest: https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/avoid-combining-selectors.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```
fiscalYear$ = this.store$.select(this.tableStoreService.getFiscalYear);
isLoading$ = this.store$.select(this.tableStoreService.tableSelectors.getLoading);
isReportLoading$ = this.store$.select(isReportLoading);
isExportAvailable$ = combineLatest([
    this.fiscalYear$, 
    this.isLoading$, 
    this.isReportLoading$
]).pipe(map(([year, isLoading, isReportLoading]) => return year < 2022 && isLoading && isReportLoading));
```

and then just use isExportAvailable$ with the async pipe in your template.